# Can't serialize records, in F#, with json.net

Tags: f#, json.net

A very basic example:

```
type private test =
    {
        a : string
        b : string list
    }

let t = { a = "hello"; b = ["1"; "2"] }
let s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t)
```

This will produce an empty string.

I have seen that json.net supports F# and that there are a lot of posts related to enum types, etc but I'm not there yet: I'm trying to serialize something very simple.

Many posts point toward another json serializer project, called Chiron, but it was updated a year ago and they're still like:

> *We’re working on Guides and reference content for working with Chiron, so keep an eye on the Updates*
>   Is there something obvious I haven't seen?

So ideally, working with json.net would be better, especially since I'm used to it in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that Json.Net only serializes public fields of F# records. When you mark the record as `private`, all its fields also become private and those are ignored. The following works as expected for me:

```
type test =
    {
        a : string
        b : string list
    }

let t = { a = "hello"; b = ["1"; "2"] }
let s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t)
```

This produces the expected JSON:

```
{"a":"hello","b":["1","2"]}
```

Comment: ok, I assumed that it would skip the private field, but if the type is private, as long as we're within the same context, it should have access to the object.