# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject cannot deserialize string returned by JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: f#, json.net

I can't figure out why JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() will not properly deserialize from the string created by JsonConvert.SerializeObject. All the values of my object are set to default value (0).

```
type Point =
    struct
        val x : float
        val y : float
        new(x, y) = 
        {
            x = x
            y = y
        }
     end

type ObjA =
    struct
        val id : int
        val point : Point
        new (id, point) = 
        {
            id = id
            point = point
        }
     end
```

If I do the following x, y, and id are all set to 0 (or 0.0).

```
let p = new Point(1.9, 2.5)
let serializedStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ObjA(1, p))
let deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjA>(serializedStr)
printfn "ID = %d" deserializedObj.id //This is 0
```

Why can't I deserialize back to the object I serialized?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wvc61u.  What f# and Json.NET versions are you using?

Comment: That being said, since you are using structs, you *may* need to add `[<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor>]` to the parameterized constructor to get Json.NET to pick it up in preference to the default constructor, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxAZxZ.

Comment: Of if your types are actually `private` in your real code, you might be hitting [Can't serialize records, in F#, with json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58702479).  If that's the case, mark your members with `[<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty>]` and your constructor with `[<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor>]`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/LlsyWx.

Comment: @dbc thanks! I added the attribute to the ctor and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `struct` types, Json.NET may not be picking up your parameterized constructors in preference to the default non-parameterized constructors.<sup>1</sup>  To force usage of the parameterized constructors, mark them with [`[<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor>]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) like so:

```
type Point =
    struct
        val x : float
        val y : float
        [<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor>] new(x, y) = 
        {
            x = x
            y = y
        }
     end

type ObjA =
    struct
        val id : int
        val point : Point
        [<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor>] new (id, point) = 
        {
            id = id
            point = point
        }
     end
```

.NET Fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxAZxZ).

---

<sup>1</sup> I was not able to reproduce the problem with the simple example shown in your question using Json.NET 13.0 and FSharp.Core version 4.3, see see .NET Fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wvc61u).  Perhaps your actual types are more complex or you are using versions other than what is available on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ for F#.